# Importing Ionic-Native File plugin in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic-native

I am attempting to use the [ionic native file plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/), but am receiving an error when attempting to run the app after installation

Partial app.module.ts file:

```
    ...
    import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
    ...
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [],
      imports: [
        ...
      ],
      providers: [
        ...
        File
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Error in console is

Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

[image]

Answer (score 1):

install

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
npm install @ionic-native/file --save
```

import `app.module.ts` like this

```
import { File } from "@ionic-native/file/ngx";

providers: [
    File
]
```

Comment: @ionic-native/file/ngx does not exist after running those install commands. https://ibb.co/jT9zvk7

Comment: that directory does not exist for me after running those commands. thanks, i'll continue to look into it